# how to make Azure Function available only for selected users using AAD

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-functions, authorization, azure-ad-msal

I have an Azure Function (let's call it Function1) which I want to make available only for selected users (via AAD in my organization).
In my solution Function1 is consumed by a desktop client app (let's call it Client), which should take care for authenticating the user (if possible also authorizing) and sending the http request to Function1.

Here's how I set it all up (and it doesn't work as expected - everyone in my organization is able to use Function1 currently).

1. I created a dedicated app registration on Azure (let's call it AppReg)
2. I added the users who should have access to Function1 in Enterprise Applications (for the AppReg) - Users and groups section. Settings (User / Default access)
3. I assigned Authentication using the AppReg in Function1, it will return 401 when not authorized
4. The signature of Function1 is:

```cs
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
```

5. Client uses MSAL for authenticating the user. The process is exactly like in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-desktop) tutorial
6. Here is the snippet that sends the request to Function1:

```cs
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.IdToken);
HttpResponseMessage postResponse = await HttpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

What should I do differently to only let specified users use Function1 and restrict any other users?

---

EDIT:

This is how I eventually made it to work:

1. I created separate app registrations for Client and Function1
2. In Function1 app reg I exposed API (user_impersonation) and added Client app as its client
3. In Client app registration I added API permission to the Function1 (delegated / user_impersonation). It also has permission to the Microsoft Graph api User.Read / delegated
4. I removed all API permissions from Function1 app reg
5. In Function1 app reg I added App Role (let's call it Role1), this assures that I have the "roles" claim in the aquired JWT
6. I assigned users to both app (in Enterprise App) with the created App Role
7. I added Authentication with Microsoft AAD in Function1, specified Function1 App registration as identity provider and added "api://{Function1 app reg guid}" as allowed token audience
8. Here is a snippet of how I aquire access token and post to Funcion1 from client application:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    static App()
    {
        CreateApplication(true);
    }

    public static void CreateApplication(bool useWam)
    {
        var builder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
            .WithAuthority($"{Instance}{Tenant}")
            .WithDefaultRedirectUri();

        if (useWam)
        {
            builder.WithExperimentalFeatures();
            builder.WithWindowsBroker(true);  // Requires redirect URI "ms-appx-web://microsoft.aad.brokerplugin/{client_id}" in app registration
        }
        _clientApp = builder.Build();
        TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(_clientApp.UserTokenCache);
    }

    private static string ClientId = "{Client app reg id}";
    private static string Tenant = "{my organisation tenant id}";
    private static string Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
    private static IPublicClientApplication _clientApp;

    public static IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApp { get { return _clientApp; } }
}

//aquiring token and posting to Function1:
string[] scopes = new string[] { "api://{Function1 app reg id}/user_impersonation" };
var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
var client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
var postResponse = await HttpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

9. Here is how I authorize only allowed users in Function1 code:

```cs
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
{

    var roles = req.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "roles");
    if (roles == null || roles.Value != "{Role1 value}")
        return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized);
```

I'm rather a newbie in Azure, web development and authentication/authorization. Could anyone smarter than me please give a comment:

1. If such set-up makes sense?
2. Does it have any security vulnerabilities?
3. Was every step necessary or is there any extra step that I should take?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/38269/setting-up-authorization-in-azure-for-a-desktop-ap.html I found here the way I can authorize the client app using roles claim, but that doesn't prevent Function1 being used by unauthorized users...

Comment: I think your seems architecture alright, `MSAL` fine in this case. No `security vulnerabilities` I haven't seen so far.

Comment: No problem you are welcome!