# How to add the permissions in the access token of Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, permissions, microsoft-graph-api, postman, sendmail

I want to consume the Microsoft Graph API to Send an email.
So, The Steps that I have followed are :
I want to get the access token first to send the mail through Microsoft Send Mail API.
For getting the access token, I have been trying the client credentials flow to get the access token and tried the following curl from Postman.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/85173d93-99ef-4dff-9b45-495719659133/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --header 'Cookie: fpc=AnGmtKaDzItFhP3TSH4j_oCmg-KtAwAAAKMJi9gOAAAAdjbDngIAAAB7DYvYDgAAAA; stsservicecookie=estsfd; x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_id=f0599628-cd3a-4478-84f0-563cb5a10f3b' \
    --data-urlencode 'scope=api://f0599628-cd3a-4478-84f0-563cb5a10f3b/.default' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_secret=e._hTCMiSgT2zr6h0U4_AEg-3.tDE71Nz~' \
    --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

[image]

I am getting the access token from this endpoint but there are no permissions in this access token.

So, When I try to send mail I get the following error.

[image]

Please help.
Let me know if any further info is required.

[image]

These are the permissions that I have already added for sending email but still cannot figure out what is the issue.

Comment: You should add permission for `Microsoft graph` under `azure active directory` then `App Registration` then go to `API Permission` on `azure portal` please see the [link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions). If need details help feel free to ask.

Comment: You're using "(...)/.default" as scope, that means that the default permissions are used that you've granted for your registered application inside the azure portal.
As @MdFaridUddinKiron said, you have to add the required permissions there. You can also use MS' Graph Explorer to determine required permissions (under modify permissions tab): https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I have edited my question and added the screenshot of all the permissions that I have included. but still I cannot send email.

Comment: Because you haven't accepted the `grant admin consent`, add that , your problem would resolve.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron So, Whoever is the admin , I will have to ask him for the consent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you haven't accepted the `Grant admin consent` you could do that like below:

[image]

> **Note:** After adding required permission just click on `Grant admin consent` button. Your page should look like as above picture.
>
> **Update:** You should have `Mail.Send` `Application Permission` then accept the `consent` hope it will allow the permission on token.

Hope that would help. Let me know if you still have any concern.

Comment: But the admin consent is required is 'Yes' in your case & in my case, the admin consent required column says 'No' in every row. Please help me clear this.

Comment: How did you do that? You should have `global admin` role in the `azure tenant`

Comment: `No` means you do not required admin concent, but make sure your token has `Mail.Send` permission and you check your token here [https://jwt.io/](https://jwt.io/) But why your `status` is empty? it should be `checked` like my sample

Comment: Yes, I am not getting the permission in my token, That is the issue. I don't know why my status is empty.

Comment: I believe you are trying `Dedicated permission`, for email add `Application permission`. Let me know if that works after.

Comment: Ohh ! Maybe you are right, When I am adding application permissions. It is asking for admin consent. But Why delegated permissions are not working and adding up in the access token ?

Comment: Because I guess you are using `client_credential` authentication protocol which requires application permission.

Comment: is there any other grant flow that does not require application permissions & require delegated permissions ?

Comment: Not at all, each of the protocol requires either of the permission. `client_credential` app permission and `auth code` dedicated permission, hope you are clear now

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I see you're quite experienced with Azure, may I ask you to visit my question and perhaps give your opinion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68440258/how-to-make-azure-function-available-only-for-selected-users-using-aad